# What's the easiest way to update the units command on a Mac?

Tags: macos, command-line

What's the easiest way to update the units command on a Mac? I don't think I have any package managers installed.

I just came across the units command for the first time:

```
0ony:sse-py stphqu0$ units
586 units, 56 prefixes
You have: 7 miles
You want: km
    * 11.265408
    / 0.088767313
You have:
```

Actually I found `units` [at this entertaining read on HN, "The 500 Mile Email".](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9338708)

The poster has more than 1000 units, I have less than 600. When I tried typing `3 millilightseconds` as in the post, the unit was unrecognized. This is a pretty useful utility and I'd like to get more units, how do I get more?

Answer (score 3):

Yosemite (OS X 10.10.2) provides `units` version 1.0

```
$ units -version

  units version 1.0  Copyright (c) 1993 by Adrian Mariano
                    This program may be freely distributed
usage: units [-f unitsfile] [-q] [-v] [from-unit to-unit]
```

You can install `gunits` 2.01 with [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org)

```
$ gunits -V
GNU Units version 2.01
with readline, with utf8, locale en_US,
Units database in /opt/local/share/units/definitions.units
Personal units file in /Users/corti/.units

Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Units comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of GNU Units
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
```

with 2559 units, 85 prefixes and 66 nonlinear units, or `gunits` 2.02 with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).

You can also build it from scratch with the [official distribution](https://www.gnu.org/software/units/) (version 2.11)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a result of the version of `units` installed.

Version 1.88 has 2526 units it can convert.  Earler versions have less, and later versions have more.

If you have compiled it yourself, you can just download a newer version. If you have installed it via your distribution's package manager, then you probably have the latest supported version, though most flavours of GNU/Linux have ways to get newer versions.

Comment: "If you have installed it via your distribution's package manager" — the OP is using OS X.

Comment: @slhck Check the times - the op didn't indicate OSX until the edit

Comment: I know, I was just pointing it out to you so you could fix (or delete) the answer.